# Why is absence of array index in "extern char name[]" not affecting strlen(name) but causing error for sizeof(name)?

Tags: c, sizeof, extern, strlen

Now,from what I understand,the `extern` in the declaration of `name[]` tells the compiler that its definition is somewhere else (In my program,I have defined it below the part where I have used it).But why then there is different consequence for `strlen()` and `sizeof`?`strlen()` works fine but for `sizeof()` I get the error:

`invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'char[]' |`

Here's my program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

extern char name[];

int main()
{
printf("%d,%d",strlen(name),sizeof(name));
}

char name[]="Bryan";
//char name[6]="Bryan"; //Neither of these make sizeof work
```

I tried to reason it out based on my understanding of the `extern` keyword,but I have hit a bottleneck.So please give your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `sizeof` doesn't know the contents the variable at the point where `sizeof` is, but `strlen` doesn't care about the compile-time size, it simply walks from the beginning of the string until it finds a NUL character marking the end of the string.

For example:

```
 char name[40] = "Bryan";

 ... 

    size_t size = sizeof(name);
    size_t len = strlen(name)

    strcat(name, " Adams"); 

    printf("%s: len=%zd, size=%zd, strlen(name)=%zd\n", 
           name, len, size, strlen(name));
```

This will show

```
Bryan Adams: len=5, size=40, strlen(name)=11
```

Answer (score 3):

`name` is defined after the function `main`, so the compiler cannot tell you what is the size of `name`.

`sizeof` is an operator that is evaluated at compile-time (except with VLAs), and the symbol `name` will be associated with the declaration afterwards, during the linking phase.

One solution is to write the size of the array in the declaration:

```
extern char name[6];
```

Then it is your responsibility to make sure that the size is the same in both declaration and definition. A macroconstant would be useful.

Comment: Just make sure you don't "fool" the compiler by using one size in the extern declaration and another in the actual variable definition - that will lead to "interesting" problems.